# Replace BLOBs with other BLOB in MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, sed

I have the database in MySQL. I need the dump of this database in another environment, but this dump needs to be a little bit different from the original one. What I would like to achieve is to replace 3 columns in one of my tables with "fake default" values.

The problem is that one of the columns is the type of `longblob` and I have no idea, what I could do with it. With other situation which is quite similar to this, I saw an example where bash script is running `mysqldump` command and then `cat` the dump and perform in it `grep` and `sed` in order to modify the dump. I was trying to find any information if it is possible with command `mysqldump`, but I didn't find anything useful.

What I was thinking about is maybe I could create a bash script/cronjob, which will create a new table almost same as the existing one, but the difference would be desirable values instead of the original one. Then it would create a dump of the whole database and finally with `grep` and `sed` rename the newly created table with the name of the original one, which would be removed.

I don't know if there is any other way to do this. The perfect solution would be just performing an `UPDATE` operation on the fly of creation mysqldump.

So my question is if there is an easy way to achieve this? Or maybe is something that I missed?

Comment: please add sample(s) of input and expected outputs in CODE TAGS in your post too now and let us know then.

Comment: It's probably easier to create table in another database DB_FAKE named as the original table, insert from select into it with blob fields changed to fake. Then use mysqldump to dump schema from original db and table and another run of mysqldump to dump data only from DB_FAKE table. No grep/sed/etc needed with such approach.